# Do not shoot new animation until the current does not end

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following animation to a leaping animation

```
$("#bounce").click(function() {
    doBounce($(this), 3, '10px', 300);       
});


function doBounce(element, times, distance, speed) {
    for(i = 0; i < times; i++) {
        element
            .animate({marginTop: '-='+distance},speed)
            .animate({marginTop: '+='+distance},speed);
    }        
}
```

But, when I click several times on the element, various animation starts, thus forming a stack of events. I would like to click and while the current animation does not end, not be possible to launch other shots, even if I click on the element. How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use the [`:animated`](https://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/) selector:

```
function doBounce(element, times, distance, speed) {
    if (element.is(":not(:animated)")) {
        for(i = 0; i < times; i++) {
            element
                .animate({marginTop: '-='+distance},speed)
                .animate({marginTop: '+='+distance},speed);
        }
    }        
}
```

Comment: To avoid confusion, my initial answer had an issue with parenthesis. I have since edited/fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

There a several ways, but I would suggest you use Javascript `scope` to set a bool that returns back to true if the animations are finished. See [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gu4a9e3u/) and hit test a few times when it's animating.

```
(function () {

    var animate = true;

    $("#bounce").click(function () {
        // Only fire when true, which it is by default.
        if (animate) {
            doBounce($(this), 3, '10px', 300);
        }
    });


    function doBounce(element, times, distance, speed) {

        // Set to false to prevent new calls. 
        animate = false;

        for (i = 0; i < times; i++) {
            element.animate({
                marginTop: '-=' + distance
            }, speed)
                .animate({
                marginTop: '+=' + distance
            }, speed);
        }

        // Set the var back to true after animations are finished.
        // https://api.jquery.com/promise/
        element.promise().done(function () {
            animate = true;
            alert(animate);
        });

    }

})();
```

Answer (score 0):

One other solution is a throttle function. A throttle function wraps another (child) function and prevents calls to the child from happening more than once every n milliseconds. Here's an example using the fantastic lodash library:

```
var doBounce = _.throttle(function(element, times, distance, speed) {
    // here, put your original doBounce code
}, lengthOfAnimation);
```

Now, no matter how many times you call `doBounce(/* some arguments */);`, the actual code won't run more than once every lengthOfAnimation milliseconds.

Of course, this will only work if the animation is the same length every time.

lodash: https://lodash.com/
throttle: https://lodash.com/docs#throttle

Comment: I did not know these libraries, I'll take a look, thank you!